# Ubuntu trying to run .js file getting throw err;

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, ssh, vps

So i moved to the directory where the .js file is located and i opend it with `node filename.js` got nodejs and everything installed on the ubuntu VPS and i get error:

```
throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'is-property'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/bot/node_modules/steamcommunity-mobile-confirmations/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/is-my-json-valid/node_modules/generate-object-property/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

what is the problem? or m i trying to run this file completly wrong?

Comment: Is your `NODE_PATH` set up so that the script can find its dependencies?

Comment: Looks like your dependencies weren't fully installed. rm -r node_modules and reinstall.

Comment: `npm install` is your hero.

Comment: when i do which nodejs it says it is in /usr/bin/nodejs but the folder doesnt even exists did it break when it was installing maybe?

Comment: @danilodeveloper
this is what i get when i try to install npm
`
`npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies`
`npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic`
`npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"`
`npm ERR! node v4.4.3`
`npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1`
`g.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to run a script with a `package.json` file, that should define all the dependencies you need. All that's left to do is run `npm install` in the project directory.

If there's no `package.json` defining dependencies, you'll need to install each missing dependency. As you've found out, it'll throw a missing module error if they're missing. You might run into this issue multiple times if there are multiple missing modules. To remedy that, either dive into the code, and look for `require('package-name')` statements that don't reference a local path. (E.g. `require('./package')` is a local file, whereas `require('package')` will look for an `npm` installed module.) Alternatively, you can just keep trying to run it, and install each missing dependency manually until it stops spitting out errors.

I highly recommend creating a `package.json` if one doesn't exist yet. You can use `npm init`, and any installed packages should be automatically added to it. Then you can save additional packages to it using `npm install package-name --save`, or `npm install package-name -S`. That way, if you use the same code on another machine/in another directory, you don't have to copy over the `node_modules` folder, as you can specify which packages/versions you want and install them with a single `npm install`.

Additionally, you may wish to read up on what the `package.json` file is in relation to node.

[NPM Docs on `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Comment: so if i understand in the .js file i've got 

`var md5 = require('md5');`
`var io = require('socket.io').listen(g_ServerPort);`
`var mysql = require('mysql');`
`var request = require('request');`
`var fs = require('fs');`
`var numeral = require('numeral');`
`var speakeasy = require('speakeasy');`
`var Random = require("random-js");`
`var random = new Random(Random.engines.mt19937().autoSeed());` and i need to install all these missing packages ?

Comment: @lenart95 For many of them, yes. However, there's a special exception in there. The `fs` module is actually a core Node module, and doesn't need to be installed. [More info on the `fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) So, you should be able to run this command to install the missing modules: `npm install --save md5 mysql request numeral speakeasy random-js` This will install them, and save the dependencies to the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to install a dependency. 
Try running the following command in your terminal

`npm install is-property --save`